# Neater way to merge this conditional entry query?

Tags: templating

I know there's a better way to do this - eg by merging in the `relatedTo` parameter if categorySlug is defined rather than defining 2 different queries, but I can't for the life of me figure it out... how would you simplify this?

```
{% if (categorySlug is defined) and (categorySlug != null) %}
   {# GET CONTENT FROM ONE CATEGORY #}
   {% set contentQuery = craft.entries
   .section(contentSection)
   .isFeatured('not 1')
   .relatedTo(craft.categories.slug(categorySlug))
%}
{% else %}
   {# GET ALL CONTENT #}
   {% set contentQuery = craft.entries
   .section(contentSection)
   .isFeatured('not 1')
   %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```twig
{% set query = craft.entries.section(contentSection).isFeatured('not 1') %}

{% if (categorySlug is defined) and (categorySlug != null) %}
   {# GET CONTENT FROM ONE CATEGORY #}
   {% set contentQuery = query.relatedTo(craft.categories.slug(categorySlug)).all() %}
{% else %}
   {# GET ALL CONTENT #}
   {% set contentQuery = query.all() %}
{% endif %}
```

Or if you want to be fancy ;)

```twig
{% set query = craft.entries.section(contentSection).isFeatured('not 1') %}

{% set contentQuery = ((categorySlug is defined) and (categorySlug != null)) ? query.relatedTo(craft.categories.slug(categorySlug)).all() : query.all() %}
```

Comment: Thanks Oli looking forward to testing this out :) :)

Comment: Working like a treat :thumbsup: